# Decode GET request with UseNumber

Tags: go

I have the following code that makes a request to Elasticsearch:

```
// Prepare request
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.Header.Add("Authorization", ES_AUTH)

// Make request
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

d := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
d.UseNumber()

var x interface{}
if err = d.Decode(&x); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("decoded to %#v\n", x)
```

The output is this:

```
decoded to map[string]interface {}{"took":"2", "timed_out":false, "_shards":map[string]interface {}{"total":"1", "successful":"1", "failed":"0"}, "hits":map[string]interface {}{"total":"15", "max_score":"1.0", "hits":[]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"_index":"reports2", "_type":"insiders", "_id":"cbaf7513-0046-4929-a740-afe13d6616b4", "_score":"1.0", "_routing":"524364278561685819", "_source":map[string]interface {}{"insider_mean":"420.7546961325966",  "friend_total":"3.7859686E7", "sum_of_followers":"3.531951269E10", "follower_total":"50000.0"}}}}}
```

I am trying to use `d.UseNumber()` to get the output to have integer numbers where possible, instead of using floats for everything.  I was expecting `"friend_total"`, `"sum_of_followers"`, and `"follower_total"` to have integer-style values.

If I make the same request with postman you can see that these values should be whole numbers:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 15,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "reports2",
        "_type": "insiders",
        "_id": "cbaf7513-0046-4929-a740-afe13d6616b4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_routing": "524364278561685819",
        "_source": {
          "insider_mean": 420.7546961325966,
          "sum_of_followers": 35319512690,
          "follower_total": 50000,
          "friend_total": 37859686
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I was unable to replicate the error in [this Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CBM7ksLrWN) so I think that the error may be because of the request itself, and not the decoding.

---

Edit:

I have discovered that doing a curl request returns the payload, so now I am certain that the decoding is not the problem.

```
curl localhost:9200/524364278561685819/insiders/_search\?size\=1                   
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":15,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"reports2","_type":"insiders","_id":"cbaf7513-0046-4929-a740-afe13d6616b4","_score":1.0,"_routing":"524364278561685819","_source":{"insider_mean":420.7546961325966,"sum_of_followers":3.531951269E10,"follower_total":50000.0,"friend_total":3.7859686E7}}]}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You are using `json.UseNumber`. The values like `3.531951269E10` are in a float format, so they can only be displayed as is or converted to a float64. `json.Number` can't convert that to an integer, and will display `strconv.ParseInt: parsing "3.531951269E10": invalid syntax` if you try.

Comment: In ElasticSearch the numbers are stored as Longs.  When I query it with Postman I get back Longs.  When I query it will Go I get back Floats instead of Longs.

Comment: The unmodified output from curl is for example is `3.531951269E10`, which is a float. You can check yourself if that can be converted to an Int64 without any loss in precision, but that's not something that `json.Number` does for you.

Comment: You're correct.  It looks like Postman was doing some conversions behind the scenes and piping the `curl` output to `jq` does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the curl output indicated, Elasticsearch was actually giving the results in floating point format.  It seems the Postman and `jq` do the conversion for you, so my solution for now is to just make a system call to `jq`:

```
// Make request
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

// Use jq to convert the floating point stuff to Longs / Ints
cmd := exec.Command("jq", ".")
cmd.Stdin = resp.Body
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
err = cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Decode the output from jq
d := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(out.Bytes())
d.UseNumber()

var x interface{}
if err = d.Decode(&x); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("decoded to %#v\n", x)
```

To clarify about Postman / curl:

> (They) are simply using a different format for the float. there is no
>   such thing as an integer in JSON, so 35319512690 is just a float
>   without the decimal point which equivalent to both 35319512690.0 and
>   3.531951269E10  - JimB

Comment: jq and postman are _not_ converting the numbers to integers for you, they are simply using a different format for the float. there is no such thing as an integer in JSON, so `35319512690` is just a float without the decimal point which equivalent to both `35319512690.0`  and  `3.531951269E10`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will add that to my answer